# OroCRM How to expose and extended field to the api?

Tags: orocrm

After adding a Status select to the CalendarEvent.  I wish to have it returned in the /api/rest/latest/calendarevents results but it does not appear there.

How do I get new fields to be returned as part of the api results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"/api/rest/latest/" is a deprecated plain API that is not supported anymore.

It's recommended to use a new JSON API. You can find documentation on it in "/api/doc". Calendar events are not exposed by default to this API, but's it's can be enabled with the simple configuration:

1. Create a file in a bundle `Resources/config/oro/api.yml` with below content

   ```
   api:
     entities:
       Oro\Bundle\CalendarBundle\Entity\CalendarEvent: ~
   ```
2. Then run the command

   ```
   php bin/console oro:api:doc:cache:clear
   ```
3. Now you can go to "api/doc" and find there "calendarevents".

As a result, you will have new API endpoints for calendar events and these endpoints include all the entity fields, including extended select fields.

For more details on using and extending REST API, please follow [the documentation](https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/api/).

Comment: This worked than you, but the start and end dates are not available as filters

Comment: Found it "Filters for fields that have a database index are enabled automatically. Filters by all other fields should be enabled explicitly, if necessary."  Had to add them to the api config too.